# Get the default value of a textarea using Jquery

Tags: jquery, textarea

How do i get the default value of a textarea using Jquery. I referred the following question
[Default text on textarea jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771794/default-text-on-textarea-jquery)
but am getting undefined as the answer

HTML:

```
<textarea id="comments">dsfdtert</textarea>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($('#comments').data('defaultval'));
});
```

see the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/7cmEc/

Comment: If you read that answer again, you will see the code associates the initial value with the element using `data()`. Since you do not perform this step, accessing that data later on indeed returns `undefined`.

Comment: any reason you can not just use straight javascript?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi : oops !!.. thank you . i did not notice that properly.

Comment: @Four_lo: nope . i have to use jquery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On pageload, you'd just use the `text()` or `val()` methods to get the default text in the textarea:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($('#comments').text());
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7cmEc/1/)

to set the default text to a data variable for later use, you'd do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#comments').data('default', $('#comments').text());
});
```

and later you can call

```
var default = $('#comments').data('default');
```

to retrieve it

Comment: thank you :-) . a straight answer which i didn't think off. .text() worked.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Adeneo's answer as it didn't quite work out of the box i had this:

//saves the default value of the text area before we modify it.

```
var textAreaDefault = $('#mailMessage').data('default', $('#mailMessage').val());
```

Then:

```
var defaults = $('#mailMessage').data('default');

textAreaDefault.val(defaults);
```

I found having a value called default doesn't work as that's a reserved keyword.